# MySQL change a column to unique

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique, alter

I have a database table that saved users profile information.
Sometimes when users register, they get duplicated with an extra column with same records, sometimes not.

So, I wonder if I put Unique on the column Email to make sure the user don't dup when register.

I think it should be something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE idx_row_unique(email);
```

But in case the Unique give error, how do I undo it?

Just scare that after I change it, I don't know how to undo it.

Answer (score 2):

If there are duplicate emails, the alter table should fail. So you're safe with that!

Comment: Even like the function force the database to create 2 column identical?

Comment: Because I don't why sometimes, my function register saved with the user 2 times identical. So, I want to check it, and Keep one and remove the other.

Comment: So, if now you have 2 times the same mail in your field, the `alter table` statement will fail.
For the future, if you have a function that saves the data in the database, you need to change that to consider the new conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd export the table structure and data first.  That way if you need to put it back, you have the SQL right there.

Comment: is there a way to export it? I didn't create the database

Comment: If you have access to phpMyAdmin for the database there is an export feature.  There is no way that I know of to do it through code.